# Updating data in sql from jtable

Tags: java, sql, syntax, sql-update

My last questions/problems are solved thank you for the advice.
In which, I have another problem encountered says:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-1

My code in updating is when click from a jtable it will be shown in a textfield, my code:

```
> try{
>              DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)tbl_stud.getModel();
>                model.fireTableDataChanged();
>             int row=tbl_stud.getSelectedRow();
>             String tbl_click=(tbl_stud.getModel().getValueAt(row, row).toString());
>           String sql="Select * from students where id_num='"+tbl_click+"';"; 
>             pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
>         rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);
>             if(rs.next()){
>                 String add1=rs.getString("id_num");
>                 up_idnum.setText(add1);
>                 String add2=rs.getString("fname");
>                 up_fname.setText(add2);
>                 String add3=rs.getString("mname");
>                 up_mname.setText(add3);
>                 String add4=rs.getString("lname");
>                 up_lname.setText(add4);
>                 
>                 String add8=rs.getString("username");
>                 up_username.setText(add8);
>                 String add9=rs.getString("password");
>                 up_pass.setText(add9);
>                 update_table();
>             }
>             
>             
>         }
>         catch(Exception o){
>             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, o);
>             
>         }
>     }
```

but i always get that error, how can i prevent it? thank you.

Comment: I would guess that the error occurs on the 5th line of your code due to the table having no row selected, so the `getSelectedRow()` method returns -1. You will have to test for the -1 value and only continue your processing if row > -1. Also, it looks like `.getValueAt(row, row)` should be `.getValueAt(row, column)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String tbl_click=(tbl_stud.getModel().getValueAt(row, row).toString());
```

In Model you need to get value of selected row and column index of id num.

```
String tbl_click=(tbl_stud.getModel().getValueAt(row, columnNo).toString());
```